# RegEx to ignore square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

My Regex is `(?:[^\S\n]|[^[:cntrl:]])*`

If I try and match `Benjamin Edward Ben` it matches the whole string, ie "Benjamin Edward Ben".

If I try and match text with square brackets, ie: "Benjamin Edw[ard] Ben" it matches up to the first square bracket, ie "Benjamin Edw".

If I try and match text with any other text, ie "Benjamin Edw*ard^ Ben" it matches the whole string, ie "Benjamin Edw*ard^ Ben".

How do I change my regex so it matches the whole string even if it has square brackets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what character do you want to allowed to be matched

Comment: Please elaborate. I am having trouble understanding what your question is ezactly. would a simple `([\w\s\[\]]+)` work?

Comment: @Anirudh - I wanna match the whole string - I want that regex (?:[^\S\n]|[^[:cntrl:]])* to return Benjamin Edw[ard] Ben....atm it returns only Benjamin Edw

Comment: In that case, Let me insert my comment as an answer

Comment: i mean what characters do you want to match..do you want to match space,alphabets,digits,control characters???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `[:cntrl:]`..Change it to `\p{Cc}`

`[:cntrl:]` class format is not supported in .net

`\p{Cc}` would match control characters similar to `[:cntrl:]`

Your regex would be

```
 (?:[^\S\n]|[^\p{Cc}])*
```

which is similar to

```
[^\S\n\p{Cc}]*
```

---

**NOTE**

`[^\S\n]` means matching space characters except newlines.So with above regex you would also match spaces

Comment: Thanks @Anirudh & also tr33hous - sorry my question wasn't very clear. I apprecite you guys perservering...

Answer (score 1):

To match string only, I would advise simplifying to `([\w\s\[\]]+)`. Further clarification would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\\` before the square bracket in your `regex`.